# Connect second display to Lenovo M700 (DisplayPort to HDMI?)

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors, video-adapters

I have a Lenovo [ThinkCenter M700](http://lenovo.com/ca/en/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre/m-series-sff/M700-SFF/p/11TC1MDM70010GT?orgRef=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) computer (regular size, not the tiny edition):

- 2 x USB 3.0
- 2 x USB 2.0
- 1 x DisplayPort 1.2
- 1 x VGA (in use by first monitor)

And I have two [BenQ GW2282](https://www.benq.com/en-me/monitor/stylish/gw2283-22-inch/specifications.html) monitors:

- 2 x HDMI (v1.4)
- 1 x VGA

---

I've connected the first monitor via the supplied VGA cable.

Question:

How can I connect the second monitor to the computer? Do I need an adapter cable to go from the computer's DisplayPort connection to the monitor's HDMI connection?

*(The goal would be to use the option that has the best quality image.)*

Answer (score 1):

I purchased a DisplayPort to VGA Adapter:

[j5create JDA114 Display Port to VGA Adapter](https://www.staples.ca/products/2332927-en-j5create-jda114-display-port-to-vga-adapter)

[image]

It seems to work ok.

---

There are also DisplayPort to HDMI cables available on Amazon:

[DisplayPort to HDMI HDTV Cable](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B081P1VL33/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_slice_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

[image]

I haven't test that option though.